# how to get the rotation angle around y axis if i know the the initial point(x,y) and the resulted point(x',y) after rotation in 2D space

Tags: math, rotation, 2d

I have an object rotates around the y axis in 2 dimension image, i want to know the angle of rotation around y axis, if i already have the initial point(X,Y) and the point(X',Y) after rotation.
I have tried to follow the 3 dimension rotation equations (https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm) to evaluate the value of rotation angle no matter the direction of rotation,but i do not know the Z value from the 2 dimension to evaluate the rotation angle from the equations.

Comment: Can you `rotate` around an y-axis without having z-axis?

Comment: Setting z to 0 should make it a planar case, which is what you need

Comment: initial z axis is set to zero or 1 but the resulted point don't know the z axis of it, and if i set z axis to zero so the equation to get the angle witl equal to :

x' = x cos(theta), cos(theta) = X'/X , what if X = Zero ?

Comment: I think you mean rotation in the `xy-plane`. Look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: No , to be more clarified i have a face in front of camera (like web cam call ) and i want to know the rotation angle of the face if the user rotate his face in any side of his face sides , so i have the point of the face after and before the rotation but i want to know the rotation angle around y axis

Comment: You don't have the point before and after rotation. You only have a projection of the point (before and after rotation) onto the image plane. In your current formulation, you do not have enough information to solve for the angle.

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes i don't have enough information , so that's why i am asking help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that i can't know the accurate rotation angles because i don't have full information about the location of points after and before rotation , i just have a projection of points(after and before the rotation)(x,y) in 2D image(plan) as "Nico Schertler" said in the comments, so i found an approximate solution which is to map the 2D object to similar 3D model for the same object and simulate the same motion on the 3D object to know approximated information about angles, in my case i want to know the rotation angles of a human head (head pose) so i mapped some 2D head features point to another 3D model and after deep diving into mathematics i got approximated rotation matrix as it shown here (http://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/)